# Passing a string through a function. C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

```
void printInstructions();
char *getUserWord();


int main()
{
    printInstructions();
    char *baseWord = getUserWord();
    printf("%s", baseWord);
    return 0;
}


void printInstructions()
{
    printf("                      Instructions:                        \n"
   "===================================================================\n"
   "= This program is a hangman game.                                 =\n"
   "= The first user will enter the name to be guessed                =\n"
   "= After that, the second user will guess the letters of the word  =\n"
   "= the second user will loose if they have three strikes           =\n"
   "===================================================================\n");
   return;
}


char *getUserWord()
{
    static char str[20];
    scanf("%s", str);
    return str;
}
```

My function `getUserWord` accomplishes its task by passing a string. From what I read online `char *baseWord = getUserWord();` was the only way to assign the string to a variable within the main function. I do not know why this is working and I am not even sure what this is doing in memory. Below is what would make sense to me. Why would this not work?

```
 char baseWord[21];
 baseWord = getUserWord();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will solve your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getUserWord(char* str);

int main(void)
{
    char baseWord[21] = ""; /* initialize for avoiding undefined behavior in case no data is read */
     getUserWord(baseWord);
     printf("%s", baseWord);

     return 0;
}

void getUserWord(char* str)
{
    scanf("%s", str);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You've fallen for the trap of believing that a pointer and an array are the same thing.  They are not.

A string, by convention in C, is normally represented as an array of `char`, with an additional terminator of `'\0'` (the so-called nul-character) appended on the end.   So the string literal `"AB"` is represented as an array of three `char` with values `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'\0'`.

A pointer is completely different from an array and, since a string is represented using an array of `char`, a pointer and a string are completely separate things.   A pointer is a variable that contains an address in memory.

Where things get confused is the name of an array is, in a number of contexts, converted into a pointer.  For example;

```
 char x[] = "AB";
 char *p = x;
```

This assignment works, but that doesn't mean an array is a pointer, or a pointer is an array.   Instead, the name `x` is converted into a pointer to its first character.   So the initialisation is functionally equivalent to

```
 char *p = &x[0];
```

so `p` points to the character with value `'A'` in the string `"AB"`.

The same thing is happening in your code, so

```
char *getUserWord()
{
    static char str[20];
    scanf("%s", str);
    return str;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
char *getUserWord()
{
    static char str[20];
    scanf("%s", &str[0]);
    return &str[0];
}
```

In both cases, the pointer returned by `getUserWord()` has a value which is the address of `str[0]`.   That is the value that is used to initialise `baseWord` in `main()`

```
char *baseWord = getUserWord();
```

Because `baseWord` now points at the first character of an array, it can be treated AS IF it is an array.  In C, for a given value of `i`, this includes an equivalence between `baseWord[i]` (in `main()`) and `str[i]` (in `getUserWord()`).    The fact that array syntax is used does not mean that a pointer and array are the same thing.   It just means they can be worked on using the same syntax.

The important thing to realise, however, is that a pointer can be returned from a function (and the returned value assigned to, or used to initialise, another pointer) but an array cannot.  So, in `main()` this is legal;

```
 char *p = getUserWord();
 p[0] = 'X';    /*  will change str[0] in getUserWord() */
```

but this will not be;

```
 char array[20] = getUserWord();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for being clear. So there is no way to actually pass a string through an array? Also, when I say "char *getUserWord()" does that * tell the function that it is returning an address?

Comment: Your wording of your first question here is unclear - what do you mean by "pass a string through an array"?     As to the second - the declaration `char *getUserWord()` specifies a function which returns a pointer - and a pointer is a type of variable that contains an address.

Comment: By the first question I mean is it possible to actual return a string in a function.

Comment: No.  A function can return a pointer, but not an array.   It is possible to return a struct, which in turn contains an array, but that is something different.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays cannot be assigned in C. This is mandated by the C Standard<sup>1</sup>. The lvalue in your second example is `baseWord` and has the type `char[21]` which is an array.

In your first example, when you return `str`, which has the type `static char[20]`, it is converted to the type `char*` and can be returned from the function and assigned to pointer `baseWord`. Since `str` has static storage duration, the pointer points to a valid object.

If you want to return a non-static string, you can allocate it (using the function malloc), pass an existing string to a function or wrap the string with a struct.

---

<sup>1</sup>(Quoted from: ISO:IEC 9899:201X 6.3.2.1. Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 1 )
A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-
qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-
qualified type.

Answer (score -1):

This code

```
char baseWord[21];
baseWord = getUserWord();
```

won't work because what is converted from an array is not a lvalue ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.3.2.1) while a modifiable lvalue is required for the left operand of assignment operator ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.16).

You can pass pointer to an array where the string read will be stored from callee.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getUserWord(char* str);

int main(void)
{
    char baseWord[21] = ""; /* initialize for avoiding undefined behavior in case no data is read */
    getUserWord(baseWord);
    printf("%s", baseWord);

    return 0;
}

void getUserWord(char* str)
{
    scanf("%s", str);
}
```

Omitted in this example, you should check if reading is successful.